# After setting manual ip address with network manager cli, ssh connection closed and no longer accessible

Tags: networking, ssh, ip, nic, networkmanager

### Context

I have been trying to set my docker containers to each use a separate ip address, rather than opening multiple ports on the same ip. My system (Debian Bullseye) uses Network Manager to manage network interfaces, so I ran `nmcli` to configure additional ipv4 addresses on `eth0`. The system is statically assigned 192.168.4.238 by my router.

### Steps which caused the issue

- I ran `set ipv4.addresses 192.168.4.238/24,192.168.4.240/24` to add the `.240` ip to my nic.
- when prompted, I changed the `ipv4.method` to `manual`.
- After setting the ipv4 addresses, I ran `save` and `print` to verify the configuration.
- Next I ran `activate` - I have never used nmcli before, and thought this seemed like a safe command to run for good measure, but was unsure what the precise functionality of this command was. Oops!
- after running `activate`, the system seemed to hang, and after ~30 seconds I hit Ctrl-C to terminate the process.

### The issue

- After running `activate`, as mentioned above, the ssh session became unresponsive, and eventually terminated.
- I tried ssh-ing in again, but this too failed. I next ran `ping 192.168.4.238` to verify the server was still up, but the request timed out.
- `arp -a` still lists 192.168.4.238, as well as the newly created 192.168.4.240 and checking my router's active connections shows that the a device is still active at 192.168.4.238.

### Conclusion

After messing with some configuration I did not fully understand, I have lost ssh access to my server. Any suggestions on where I went wrong would be greatly appreciated, as well as any suggestions on how to regain ssh access.

Thanks!